# Acesso a ponteiro na main()

Tags: c, ponteiro

Por que na declaração como argumento na função `main()`: `char* argv[]` em vez de `char argv[]` eu consigo acessar as informações. Sei que um é ponteiro. Não consigo acessar quando não é ponteiro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%s", argv[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está acessando um *array* de *strings*. O `[]` representa o *array* e o `char *`representa a *string*. Isto é necessário porque a linha de comando pode passar vários argumentos, e todos são *strings*.

Em C não existe a *string* com um conceito próprio, ela costuma ser representada por um *array*  ou ponteiro, o mais comum, de caracteres.

Então são duas coisas distintas, por isso precisa precisa ser usado desta forma.

Em C é raro, mas há quem faça `typedef string char *;` para poder usar `string` no lugar de `char *`.

Se fosse

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Main.c).

você entenderia? É a mesma coisa.

Não consegue acessar sem o ponteiro porque aí é só um *array* de caracteres e não um *array* de *strings*, que é o esperado. Na verdade até tem como acessar, mas não será o que espera. Você tem que usar o tipo certo para o que precisa.

Answer (score 3):

Porque em C strings são vetores de caracteres, quando você declara char* argv[], você esta declarando um vetor de strings.

Para acessar a partir do índice 1 até n-vezes, 0 e o nome passado na linha de comando.

Isso é um exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *nomes[] = {"joao", "maria", "pedro"};

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(nomes) / sizeof(char* ); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", nomes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/6NOCI2

Answer (score 1):

Só para compreender melhor, ponteiros são úteis quando uma variável tem que ser acessada em diferentes partes de um programa. Seu código pode ter vários ponteiros “apontando” para a variável que contém o dado desejado.

Situações onde ponteiros são úteis:

- Alocação dinâmica de memória
- Manipulação de arrays
- Para retornar mais de um valor em uma função
- Referência para listas, pilhas, árvores e grafos