# A função main e seus argumentos. Como ela consegue atribuir aos seus argumentos argc e *argv[] os parâmetros passados via terminal?

Tags: c, c++

Para a minha pergunta ficar mais clara. Suponha que o meu programa, chamado main, precise receber uma quantidade qualquer de parâmetros do console.

Para tanto, eu teria que fazer isso.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    ...
   return 0;
}
```

Correto?

Em seguida eu compilo e executo passando os seus parâmetros.

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
```

```
$ ./main par1 par2 ... parn
```

Eu gostaria de saber como a função main consegue pegar a quantidade de parâmetros passados (que pode ser arbitrária) e jogar na variável argc e jogar todos eles dentro do array *argv[]?

Mais ainda, tem como reproduzir esse comportamento em uma função ordinária? Caso sim, Como? Poderia me fornecer um exemplo.

Faço essa pergunta por que eu estou estudando C e quero entender esse comportamento.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro leia [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

É um pouco complicado explicar isso sem escrever um livro falando de sistema operacional e como uma um executável funciona e gerenciamento de memória.

E não precisa ser passado exatamente por um terminal.

Os argumentos são passados pelo sistema operacional, é problema dele pegar aqueles valores na linha de comando que chama o executável e colocar na memória para que o executável possa ler. Obviamente que ele faz isso de uma forma padronizada que todo executável que siga esse padrão consiga pegar essa informação, mas não tem muito segredo.

Pela assinatura da função já sabemos que haverá duas informações, uma dela é um inteiro que diz quantos argumentos estão disponíveis, ou seja, qual é o tamanho do *array* que virá a seguir. E depois vem um *array* de ponteiros. Novamente, o sistema operacional é que coloca esses números em algum lugar da memória que já vou falar.

Além disso é colocado na memória os argumentos em si, ou seja, vem os textos que foram digitados todos terminados com um nulo como toda string do padrão do C deve ser. Sim, o sistema operacional segue o que foi determinado pelo C. Qualquer outra linguagem tem que funcionar da mesma forma, pelo menos a prática é assim, nada impediria ser diferente. O endereço onde cada texto foi colocado são os endereços que vão lá no *array* de ponteiros.

Esses dados todos são colocados em uma área que irá pertencer ao executável, isso já é cuidado pelo sistema de gerenciamento de memória do sistema operacional, é função dele controlar tudo isso. Os dados que você vê diretamente na assinatura da função irão em uma área especial que podemos chamar informalmente de pré-*stack* ([pilha da execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)). Embora isso seja detalhes de implementação, não precisa ser exatamente assim. Você como programador, se não está criando todo mecanismo de *runtime* da linguagem não tem que saber de nada disso.

Mas entenda que `main()` não tem nada de uma muito especial, além disso, ela pega os valores recebidos nos parâmetros da mesma forma que qualquer outra função, esses parâmetros nada mais são que [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) locais da função.

Essa é uma função ordinária. A única diferença dela é que é chamada pelo sistema operacional. E se quer saber se pode fazer isso, não, não pode, nem faz sentido.

Se não entendeu alguma coisa provavelmente pulou alguma etapa e está querendo aprender algo mais avançado que falta conhecimento fundamental.

Leia:

- [Qual a forma correta de declarar uma função main()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95133/101)
- [Acesso a ponteiro na main](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197542/101)
- [O entry point de um executavel é o endereço da memória da função main?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/344655/101)
- [Retorno da função main](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/386610/101)

Answer (score 1):

### A resposta curta é sim.

Você pode fazer isso. E como deve imaginar é uma necessidade muito comum.
Por coincidência postei um programa ontem nesse site que faz exatamente isso, e o link é esse: [para o post em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468229/108192)

**No entanto o exemplo mostra o caso para um vetor int**.**

Eu até vi uma resposta aqui bem contrária, dizendo que *"não só você não pode como não faz sentido"*, mas acho que não entendi ou não sei o que dizer.

Então vou te mostrar um programa e explicar a mecânica desse troço, porque, repito, é uma necessidade comum e eu por exemplo já expliquei isso incontáveis vezes. E não sou instrutor nem nada disso. Ou eu não entendi nada e vou postar um programa a toa.

### Porque isso é comum:

Se encaixa em um grande número de abstrações, como

- criar e percorrer um vetor de estruturas depois de ler de algum lugar o total de estruturas
- "*subir*" um arquivo para a memória em um `char**linha` com `linha[i]`correspondendo claro à linha `i` do arquivo o disco. Um editor de texto por exemplo
- carregar registros de um arquivo CSV, aqueles onde tem um registro por linha e os campos são separados por vírgulas. CSV na verdade é `char** **` mas seria outro tópico
- carregar algo como uma planilha (workbook) para a memória como texto. Isso seria no fundo um assustador `char** ** **` mas voltamos ao tópico
- para um aluno, começar boa parte daqueles programas de estruturas de dados, carregando os *Nodes* de sei lá o que para a memória antes ou para montar a estrutura

### O Programa exemplo

O programa vai preparar os argumentos e chamar uma função declarada

```
int nova_main(int, char**);
```

com essa implementação BEM FAMILIAR

```
int nova_main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("\n\tEm \"main\": %d argumentos\n\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i += 1)
        printf("%2d\t'%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
};  // nova_main()
```

Bem familiar porque é o protótipo de `main()`. Vamos até montar `argv[0]` como *"nome do programa"*.

O programa usa essa estrutura

```
typedef struct
{
    int     argc;
    char**  argv;
}   Bloco;
```

Só para você entender que pode declarar um vetor delas e preparar um número arbitrário de listas de argumentos. E também para você não ter que ficar procurando declarações pelo programa, apesar de que é minúsculo.

Para manter o programa compacto e auto-contido a entrada vai ser um vetor

```
    const int   n_parm = 12;
    const char* teste[12] =
    {
        "criando", "um", "bloco", "de",
        "parametros", "como", "o", "sistema",
        "prepara", "para", "main()", "..."
    };
```

Eu tinha usado um arquivo mas achei melhor deixar aqui tudo junto. Afinal não faz diferença alguma: São apenas strings, como seriam os argumentos na linha de comando.

### A alocação de memória para os argumentos

A lógica é bem ingênua mas muito eficiente: a memória é alocada em blocos de ponteiros a partir dessa constante

```
#define _TAMANHO_ 4
```

Conforme o bloco se esgota ele é estendido em idêntico tamanho e vida segue. Ao final dos argumentos o eventual excesso é liberado e o bloco é passado para a função `nova_main()`. Só para ficar mais meigo, ao final os parâmetros são liberados em `main()` antes de encerrar o programa.

Num programa sério você ajusta com extremo cuidado o tamanho do bloco de alocação, porque se for pequeno vai realocar toda hora e pode ficar lento. E se for muito grande vai ser um desperdício afinal. Ou aloca em páginas e usa uma lista ligada de páginas, brincando de sistema operacional.

### Eis a saída de uma execução do programa

```
Realocado bloco para 8 ponteiros
Realocado bloco para 12 ponteiros
Realocado bloco para 16 ponteiros
        13 strings no vetor de argumentos:
                1 de 13: 'nome do programa'
                2 de 13: 'criando'
                3 de 13: 'um'
                4 de 13: 'bloco'
                5 de 13: 'de'
                6 de 13: 'parametros'
                7 de 13: 'como'
                8 de 13: 'o'
                9 de 13: 'sistema'
                10 de 13: 'prepara'
                11 de 13: 'para'
                12 de 13: 'main()'
                13 de 13: '...'
        Alocados 16 ponteiros
        Lidos 13 argumentos
        3 ponteiros a liberar
        Bloco reduzido para 13 ponteiros
        Chamando nova_main() com esses argumentos

        Em "main": 13 argumentos

       0        'nome do programa'
       1        'criando'
       2        'um'
       3        'bloco'
       4        'de'
       5        'parametros'
       6        'como'
       7        'o'
       8        'sistema'
       9        'prepara'
      10        'para'
      11        'main()'
      12        '...'


        "main()" retornou 0
        Agora apaga o bloco todo e encerra


Fim
```

Eis o programa

```
#define _TAMANHO_ 4

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int     argc;
    char**  argv;
}   Bloco;

int nova_main(int, char**);

int main(void)
{
    const int   n_parm = 12;
    const char* teste[12] =
    {
        "criando", "um", "bloco", "de",
        "parametros", "como", "o", "sistema",
        "prepara", "para", "main()", "..."
    };

    // a memoria vai ser alocada em blocos de _TAMANHO_ 
    // a cada vez que faltar memoria um novo bloco
    // eh acrescentado. Ao final um trim() no bloco
    // para retornar o exato tamanho utilizado.
    // Ex: para 12 strings vai alocar para _TAMANHO_ 5
    // 5 + 5 + 5 e ao final libera 3 das 15 e retorna 
    // argc = 12 e os 12 ponteiros, como esperado
    //
    // o primeiro argumento e o nome do progama
    // pura frescura, eh um exemplo apenas

    Bloco ex; // exemplo
    int N = _TAMANHO_; // primeiro bloco
    ex.argc = 0;
    ex.argv = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * _TAMANHO_);
    const char* programa = "nome do programa";
    ex.argv[ex.argc] = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(programa));
    strcpy(ex.argv[ex.argc], programa);
    ex.argc += 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n_parm; i += 1)
    {   // carrega cada string
        if (ex.argc >= N)
        {   // acabou a memoria
            N = N + _TAMANHO_;
            char* novo = realloc(ex.argv, (N * sizeof(char*)) );
            printf("Realocado bloco para %d ponteiros\n", N);
            ex.argv = (char**)novo;
        };
        ex.argv[ex.argc] = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(teste[i]));
        strcpy(ex.argv[ex.argc], teste[i]);
        ex.argc += 1;
    };  // for()
    printf("\t%d strings no vetor de argumentos:\n", ex.argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.argc; i += 1)
    {
        printf("\t\t%d de %d: '%s'\n", 1+i, ex.argc, ex.argv[i]);
    };
    // agora acerta o final, liberando os ponteiros que
    // podem estar sobrando no bloco
    // foram alocados N ponteiros. Foram usados argc
    printf("\tAlocados %d ponteiros\n", N);
    printf("\tLidos %d argumentos\n", ex.argc);
    if (N == ex.argc)
        printf("\tNada a liberar\n");
    else
    {
        printf("\t%d ponteiros a liberar\n", N - ex.argc);
        char* novo = realloc(ex.argv, (ex.argc * sizeof(char*)));
        printf("\tBloco reduzido para %d ponteiros\n", ex.argc);
        ex.argv = (char**)novo;
    };
    printf("\tChamando nova_main() com esses argumentos\n");
    int res = nova_main(ex.argc, ex.argv);
    printf("\n\n\t\"main()\" retornou %d\n", res);
    printf("\tAgora apaga o bloco todo e encerra\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.argc; i += 1)
        free(ex.argv[i]);
    free(ex.argv);
    printf("\n\nFim\n");
    return 0;
};

int nova_main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("\n\tEm \"main\": %d argumentos\n\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i += 1)
        printf("%8d\t'%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
};  // nova_main()
```

Sem entrar em discussões religiosas aqui, compilei apenas em CL 19.27 e rodei no terminal do Windows. É o mais disponível para mim.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, o compilador dá parse pelo carater de espaço vazio " ". Conta assim o número de argumentos (não esquecendo que main em "./main" é o primeiro argumento do programa). Assim se precisar de escrever um argumento com espaços têm que colocar entre aspas (Por exemplo se quiser passar o nome José Barros tem de escrever "José Barros", caso contrário vai contar como 2 argumentos por causa do espaço entre os nomes). Sabendo o nº de argumentos sinmplesmente cria um array de apontadores para carateres, em que cada apontador corresponde a um dos argumentos passados.

Acho que com esta informação já fica mais simples de criar uma função que faça o mesmo. Uma função útil para dar parse é strtok.